# replace .animate() with fadeIn/ fadeOut

Tags: jquery

im relatively new to jQuery and having a little problem. previously i've used .animate to animate my menu when i scroll down, but i have to change it to fadeIn and fadeOut. here is my code:

```
if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
bar.stop().animate({'top' : '0px'}, 1250);
} else {
bar.stop().animate({'top' : top}, 1250);
}
```

Comment: show us your html code too..

Comment: Are you using animate to hide some element?

Comment: when the user scrolls down the page, a strip slides in under the top menu, earlier i was animating that strip but now i have to fade it in/ out.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call `fadeIn/fadeOut` on your element

```
  bar.fadeOut('slow');
```

or

```
  bar.fadeIn('slow');
```

You can also attach a callback function. For more information see:

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: Thank you John for your help. one more question related to this, how do i set the top position in fadeIn like i have in .animate({'top' : '0px'}, 1250);

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
   bar.stop().fadeOut();
} else {
   bar.stop().fadeIn();
}
```

For future reference please go here:
http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

People are happier when you provide links showing you did some kind of research. Anyways, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
bar.stop().fadeOut( function() { $(this).animate({'top' : '0px'}, 1250); }, "slow");
} else {
bar.stop().fadeIn( function() { $(this).animate({'top' : '0px'}, 1250); }, "slow");
}
```

Your question is vague. But you can use any of the answer's code which suits you. And also refer to documentation because they have examples there.